# How does jprofiler automatically start recording method statistics

Tags: jprofiler

After a session has started up, I can press the `Button` under `CPU views` to record `method statistics`.
Is there a way to make `method statistics recording` start automatically after starting up the session, and not need to press that `Button` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a trigger could achieve this requirement.

[Setting a trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXsHW.jpg)